# Is there any difference between adding Tailwind when creating a project or after it is build in on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, tailwind-css

I have a project that I'm currently working on and I'm having some trouble trying to add tailwind to it.

I was able to add it by running these following snippets into my terminal`bundle add tailwindcss-rails` and `rails tailwindcss:install`, however it seems that it doesn't bring all tailwind classes and forces me to use `rake tailwindcss:build` everytime i do a minor class change. Does anyone know how can I resolve that problem? If it was the way i implemented the tailwind or is something missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you need to run `bin/dev` or `rails tailwindcss:watch`